# python xml parsing: get all child nodes, regardless of name?

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<root>

 <major-heading id="uk.org.publicwhip/wrans/2023-09-01.196930.mh" nospeaker="true">
    Department for Environment
 </major-heading>

 <minor-heading id="uk.org.publicwhip/wrans/2023-09-01.196930.h" nospeaker="true">
    Food: Waste
 </minor-heading>

 <ques id="uk.org.publicwhip/wrans/2023-09-01.196930.q0" person_id="uk.org.publicwhip/person/25307" speakername="Martyn Day" url="https://questions-statements.parliament.uk/written-questions/detail/2023-09-01/196930">
    <p qnum="196930">To ask the Secretary of State for Environment, Food and Rural Affairs, what assessment she has made of the implications for her Department's net-zero policies of not introducing new legislation on food waste.</p>
 </ques>

 <reply id="uk.org.publicwhip/wrans/2023-09-01.196930.r0" person_id="uk.org.publicwhip/person/25407" speakername="Rebecca Pow">
    ...content
 </reply>

</root>
```

The child nodes can be in any order.

I want to iterate over each child node in turn and only get the text from it if it's a `ques` or `reply` node.

In pseudocode:

```
for childnode in root.children:
  if childnode.elementname == 'ques' or childnode.elementname == 'reply':
     # do something
```

What's the best way to do this? I've looked at the python `untangle` library but I don't think it can list all children without naming them. I expect lxml can do this, but the documentation is fairly impenetrable.

Comment: Which XML parser are you using? That's pretty reasonable for ElementTree. You could also use an xpath statement like `/root/*[self::ques or self::reply]` or `/root/ques|/root/reply`. If using lxml or libxml where the query is done in C, the later would be faster on a large document.